# API: from localhost to webhosting

Tags: javascript, api, deployment

I have installed mssql server in localhost and I created api (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xT2AvjQ7q9E&list=PLNF6YK3CFS68GMnoeIdrZvPuWkt79sWIt) according to the tutorial, which returns values from the database. Everything works fine in localhost. Using the console I run "node a app.js", I get a message saying it listens on port 9000 and I see everything ok at localhost: 9000.

I have in app.js only this:

```
require("./core/server");
```

But I do not know how to transfer this functionality outside of localhost to web hosting (if at all possible).

I'm a complete beginner who is getting to know api for the first time in my life.

So I have a working api on localhost which I have to run via console. How to make api available on public hosting?

Thank you very much for your efforts to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can host on Heroku 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Also check for CORS.
You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0):

You can't access node. js from outside because it is listening on localhost IP i.e 127.0. 0.1. You need to configure node.
Read and try this.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/access-node-based-web-server-with-public-ip
However, you need to deploy to host a web server.